# IHttpClientFactory and changing the base HttpClient.BaseAddress

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

What is the best practice for IHttpClientFactory and changing HttpClient.BaseAddress?

When creating my Dependency Injection I am doing it like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyApp", c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myurl/");
        c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(handler => new HttpClientHandler()
    { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip });
```

Then when I need an HttpClient doing this:

```
var client = clientFactory.CreateClient("MyApp");
```

This works great, but there are times, during runtime that the BaseAddress needs to change.  During the run I am not able to change the BaseAddress after it has been injected.  Now I could ignore BaseAddress altogether and just send the entire address in the API call, however, I do not know if this is the correct way of doing it.  Something like this:

```
await using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync($"{addresss}/{api}");
using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
using var textReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader);
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
data = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(textReader);
```

Comment: Couple thoughts, i could have swore the base address was configurable after injection but if it's not you may want to use two clients and move the `CreateClient` closer to where you need the specific base address and use your second client there. just some ideas

Comment: @JSteward I have had no luck changing the BaseAddress when I switch from straight HttpClient to IHttpClientFactory.  Having two clients is unwanted, basically, the app allows for configuration change at run time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> there are times, during runtime that the BaseAddress needs to change. During the run I am not able to change the BaseAddress after it has been injected.

`BaseAddress` can be changed up until the first request is sent. At that point, it is locked down and cannot be changed again. The `HttpClient` factory pattern assumes that each injected client has only one `BaseAddress` (which may be unset).

> Now I could ignore BaseAddress altogether and just send the entire address in the API call, however, I do not know if this is the correct way of doing it.

Your options are:

1. Define multiple clients, one for each `BaseAddress`. This is the normal approach if you have a few well-known hosts.
2. Define a single client and do not use `BaseAddress`, passing the entire url in each call. This is perfectly permissible.
3. Define your own factory type that uses `IHttpClientFactory` to pass out `HttpClient` instances where each instance can specify its own `BaseAddress`. I would only use this more complex approach if you had some code that *required* a `BaseAddress` (e.g., Refit) but needed to use it with a dynamic host.

Comment: So regarding the second point,  will something like httpClientFactory.Create() work? Or even just with DI: constructor(HttpClient client)?

Comment: @Ssss: Either of those would work to get an `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: Option 2 seems the best for me, however I could find any docs on the issue. I keep getting an exception  : InvalidOperationException: BaseAddress must be set on the HttpClient instance.

Comment: @Xserge: Some third-party libraries (i.e., Refit) *require* a `BaseAddress`.

Comment: in same case where 3 is required, option 4 is to use a DelegatingHandler as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75478523/169336